# Trying to perform a simple recursive XML python parsing

Tags: python, xml, recursion, xpath, elementtree

I'm currently struggling at creating a simple python script which would allow me to parse a XML file in order to get the paths of particular tags.

## Input data

The XML files I need to parse typically looks like the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document>
    <Engineering version="V17"/>
    <DocumentInfo>
        <ExportSetting>WithDefaults, WithReadOnly</ExportSetting>
    </DocumentInfo>
    <SW.Blocks.GlobalDB ID="0">
        <AttributeList>
            <AutoNumber>true</AutoNumber>
            <HeaderVersion>0.1</HeaderVersion>
            <Interface>
                <Sections>
                    <Section Name="Static">
                        <Member Name="foo" Datatype="Struct" Remanence="NonRetain" Accessibility="Public">
                            <Member Name="foo1" Datatype="Bool"></Member>
                            <Member Name="foo2" Datatype="Struct">
                                <Member Name="foo2.1" Datatype="Bool"></Member>
                                <Member Name="foo2.2" Datatype="Int"></Member>
                            </Member>
                        </Member>
                        <Member Name="bar" Datatype="Struct" Remanence="NonRetain" Accessibility="Public">
                            <Member Name="bar" Datatype="Bool"></Member>
                            <Member Name="bar 1" Datatype="Bool"></Member>
                            <Member Name="bar3" Datatype="Bool"></Member>
                        </Member>
                    </Section>
                </Sections>
            </Interface>
        </AttributeList>
    </SW.Blocks.GlobalDB>
</Document>
```

## Expected output

I only care about the `<Member>` tags, and especially their `Name` attributes. What I want to do is iterate through all theses tags, and getting a list of all the bottom level child nodes (i.e all `<Member>` nodes having no child nodes themselves), as a list of xml paths (still taking care only about `Member` tags).

Thus, I would expect from the given example file the following result:

```
foo.foo1
foo.foo2."foo2.1"
foo.foo2."foo2.2"
bar.bar
bar."bar 1"
bar.bar3
```

## What I tried so far

The first script I wrote was based on minidom and a `getElementsByTagName` loop which calculated for each `Member` found its level within the XML architecture and putting it with the associated `Name` value in a list.
A second loop was used after to iterate on this list and concatenating the paths thanks to levels comparisons.
I would have kept that solution if it worked (because it's not stupid if it does, they say...), but it behaves not correctly (depending on the levels differences between two elements, it calculates the path right... or not).

I thought it would be way more efficient to perform the job using a recursive loop, but I'm struggling. Based on solutions given on StackOverflow for similar issues, I just wrote :

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

def find_rec(node, element):
    for item in node.findall(element):
        yield item
        for child in find_rec(item, element):
            yield child.attrib['Name']

print(".".join(find_rec(ET.parse("in.xml"), './Member')))
```

And it does not work at all. Running that script only outputs a single whitespace character, without any message or error.
Replacing `./Member` with `Member` does not changes anything, nor does writing just `yield child` at the second loop.

I tried other implementations with minidom without any success.

Can anyone help me fix that code (and explaining why it does not work...) ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: XPath should be `//Member` (a relative one). `./` is relative to current node that in your case is `Document`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using only the built-in module `xml.etree`:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et

def findpaths(tree, path):
    for node in tree:
        path.append(node)
        if node.tag == "Member" and not len(node): # Member node without any child
            yield list(path)
        yield from findpaths(node, path) # recurse
        path.pop()

def processpath(path):
    for node in path:
        if node.tag == "Member" and "Name" in node.attrib:
            yield escape(node.attrib["Name"]) # only capture Name for the result

def escape(name):
    if any(c in name for c in (".", " ")): # list of characters worth escaping
        return f'"{name}"'
    return name

tree = et.parse("./source.xml") # assuming your xml is there
for path in findpaths(tree.getroot(), []):
    print(".".join(processpath(path)))
```

Output:

```
foo.foo1
foo.foo2."foo2.1"
foo.foo2."foo2.2"
bar.bar
bar."bar 1"
bar.bar3
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! However, it does not work when using actual input, because (I guess) of the tags inside the bottom level `Member`... My original post was not totally accurate : these tags don't have other `Member` inside them, but are not empty.

Typical xml inside bottom level `Member` :  
`<AttributeList>
        <IntegerAttribute Name="Offset" Informative="true" SystemDefined="true">0</IntegerAttribute>
    </AttributeList>`
   
In your `findpath` function, I tried replacing your `not len(node)` statement by `not ("Member" in node.getChildren)`, without success.

Comment: Update about my previous comment : in the `findpaths()` definition, I replaced the condition by `if node.tag == "Member" and not (sum(1 for _ in node.iter("Member"))-1)` and it works like a charm!  
  
Second issue, in my actual input, the first `<Sections>` tag has a `xmlns` tag which is in fact a namespace... I didn't know about that, but the parser does! Best to just manually delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution with `beautifulsoup` (using recursion):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with open('file.xml', 'r') as f_in:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f_in.read(), 'xml')


def pretty_name(n):
    if '.' in n or ' ' in n:
        return f'"{n}"'
    return n

def get_path(m, cur_path=''):
    parent = m.find_parent('Member')
    n = (pretty_name(m['Name']) + '.' + cur_path).strip('.')
    if parent:
        return get_path(parent, n)
    return n


for m in soup.select('Member:not(:has(Member))'):
    print(get_path(m))
```

Prints:

```
foo.foo1
foo.foo2."foo2.1"
foo.foo2."foo2.2"
bar.bar
bar."bar 1"
bar.bar3
```